# prove that $X \times Y$ is a Lindelöf space

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Let be $X$ a Lindelöf space and $Y$  a compact space, prove that $X \times Y$ is a Lindelöf space.

Comment: I trying to prove that any coverage it has a finite subcoverage..

Comment: @JarbasDantasSilva That would mean $X\times Y$ is compact. You need a _countable_ subcover.

Comment: yes... countable subcover... sorry

Answer (score 3):

HINT: Let $\mathscr{U}$ be an open cover of $X\times Y$.

- Without loss of generality we may assume that each $U\in\mathscr{U}$ is of the form $V_U\times W_U$, where $V_U$ is open in $X$, and $W_U$ is open in $Y$. (Why?)
- For each $x\in X$ there is a finite $\mathscr{U}_x\subseteq\mathscr{U}$ such that $\{x\}\times Y\subseteq\bigcup\mathscr{U}_x$. (Why?)
- For each $x\in X$ let $V_x=\bigcap_{U\in\mathscr{U}_x}V_U$; $V_x$ is an open nbhd of $x$. (Why?)
- $\{V_x:x\in X\}$ is an open cover of the Lindelöf space $X$, so it has a countable subcover, say $\{V_x:x\in C\}$, where $C$ is some countable subset of $X$.

Now use the cover $\{V_x:x\in C\}$ and the families $\mathscr{U}_x$ with $x\in C$ to find a countable subcover of $\mathscr{U}$.

Comment: but these elements will belong to this coverage?

Comment: @Jarbas: I’m not sure what you’re asking. Which elements? And which cover?

Comment: I understand the elements of subcovering are like $ Vx \cap Wx$

Comment: @Jarbas: Not quite: they’re of the form $V_x\times W_U$, where $x\in C$ and $U\in\mathscr{U}_x$.

Comment: $V_x \times W_u$ it is a element of the cover (which in turn is a family of open)? (why?)

Comment: @Jarbas: Do you mean $V_x\times W_U$ and $\mathscr{U}_x$? No, it need not be, because $V_x$ need not be equal to $V_U$. But $V_x\subseteq V_U$, so $V_x\times W_U\subseteq V_U\times W_U$.

Comment: then by definition there is not a subcover...

Comment: @Jarbas: There certainly is. $\{V_x\times W_U:x\in C\text{ and }U\in\mathscr{U}_x\}$ is not a countable subcover of $\mathscr{U}$, but you can use it to find one in a very simple way.

Comment: very nice answer sir, you is a genius sir (+1)